# How can I reference the target build stage in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

You specify the target build stage with the `--target` flag like the below:

```
docker build --target production .
```

How can I reference that target build stage in Dockerfile? For example, I'd like to name a folder with the target build stage like the below:

```
FROM base AS build
WORKDIR /${TARGET_BUILD_STAGE}
```

The current workaround for this is to declare an `ARG` and pass in the same value to the build argument like this:

```
docker build --target production --build-arg TARGET_BUILD_STAGE=production .
```

I wonder if there's an official solution supported by Docker.